# implementation of ID3 algorithm in java using Eclipse IDE. But showingerror

Tags: java, algorithm, decision-tree, id3

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;

import ca.pfv.spmf.algorithms.classifiers.decisiontree.id3.AlgoID3;
import ca.pfv.spmf.algorithms.classifiers.decisiontree.id3.DecisionTree;

public class MainTestID3 {

    public static void main(String [] arg) throws IOException{
        // Read input file and run algorithm to create a decision tree
        AlgoID3 algo = new AlgoID3();
        // There is three parameters:
        // - a file path
        // - the "target attribute that should be used to create the decision tree
        // - the separator that was used in the file to separate values (by default it is a space)
        DecisionTree tree = algo.runAlgorithm(fileToPath("id3.txt"), "result", " ");
        algo.printStatistics();

        // print the decision tree:
        tree.print();

        // Use the decision tree to make predictions
        // For example, we want to predict the class of an instance:
        String [] instance = {null, "T_M", "P_M", "C_M", "F_M", "H_M", "N_M", "I_M"};
        String prediction = tree.predictTargetAttributeValue(instance);
        System.out.println("The class that is predicted you can play: " + prediction);
    }

    public static String fileToPath(String filename) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        URL url = MainTestID3.class.getResource(filename);
         return java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(),"UTF-8");
    }
}
```

THIS IS THE ERROR SHOWING :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  at ca.pfv.spmf.algorithms.classifiers.decisiontree.id3.AlgoID3.runAlgorithm(AlgoID3.java:88)    at ca.pfv.spmf.test.M
```

Comment: You will have to show us the code for `AlgoID3` class.

Comment: can you provide the first lines of the `id3.txt` file?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the ID3 code, it looks like the target attribute is may be not spelled correctly in the file or in the call to `runAlgorithm()`. The first line of the `id3.txt` should contains `"result"` somewhere.

The error you have comes in `AlgoID3.java` from the line:

> ```
> remainingAttributes[pos++] = i;
> ```

in this piece of code:

> ```
>   allAttributes = line.split(separator);
>     // make an array to store the attributes except the target attribute
>     int[] remainingAttributes = new int[allAttributes.length - 1];
>     int pos = 0;
>     // for each attribute
>     for (int i = 0; i < allAttributes.length; i++) {
>         // if it is the target attribute
>         if (allAttributes[i].equals(targetAttribute)) {
>             // save the position of the target attribute. It will be useful
>             // later.
>             indexTargetAttribute = i;
>         } else {
>             // otherwise add the attribute to the array of attributes
>             remainingAttributes[pos++] = i;
>         }
>     }
> ```

where `targetAttribute` should be "result" in your case. If there is no match found, since the `remainingAttribute` array has a (allAttributes - 1) length, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`...

Certainly the code could check this and throw an explicit exception.

Comment: There is "result" in id3.txt file here is the content of Id3.txt

Comment: result tds ph chloride fluoride hardness nitrate iron
Impure T_H P_M C_L F_H H_M N_L I_M
Pure T_M P_M C_L F_L H_L N_L I_M
Impure T_M P_M C_L F_H H_L N_L I_M
Pure T_M P_M C_L F_M H_L N_L I_M
Impure T_H P_M C_M F_H H_M N_L I_H
Impure T_H P_M C_L F_H H_M N_L I_M
Impure T_H P_M C_L F_H H_M N_L I_M
Impure T_M P_M C_L F_H H_L N_L I_M
Impure T_H P_M C_L F_H H_M N_L I_M
Impure T_H P_M C_M F_H H_M N_L I_H

Comment: So how can i check whether the value called "result" reaches at targetAttributet

Comment: I think I found the pb: in your file the separator looks like `tab` and not space. The ID3 code use `line.split(separator)` with separator being a <space> in your code. You can test, either by changing the tabs by a space in the file, or by using a separator like `"\\s+"` which is a regex that `split()` can interpret as _any_ space.